# Bootstrap Modal passing data through on('click-row.bs.table'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-table

I have to Bootstrap Modal Windows... One with a table(`#items`) and another(`#item`) with form Data.

Now i want to click on a row in the table and want to open the other modal windows and want to pass data through.

```
$('#items-table').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
    $('#items').modal('hide');
    $('#item').modal('show');
    //Need to pass row.id to #item
});
```

this is where i catch the click from the table row. Here i get the `row.id` which i want to use in my `#item` form.

```
$('#item').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  var itemId = button.data('item-id') ;// Extract info from data-* attributes

})
```

these two lines which are standing there are from a button which has a data- Attribute. This is working fine, but how i can pass the `row.id` from the table?

Comment: Maybe help you: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/crud/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured out to managed this properly:

```
    $('#items-table').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
    $('#items').modal('hide');
    $modal('#item');
    $modal.data('id', row.id);
    $modal.modal('show');
    //Need to pass row.id to #item
});
```

and catch it in the modal like:

```
$('#item').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {

  var modal = $(this);
  var id = modal.data('id');

})
```

big thanks to @wenyi for that link!